# jQuery ajax return readyState 1 or incorrect data type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I write script for Wordpress plugin and have problem with ajax response. When i want get json file, jQuery.ajax return `{readyState: 1}`.
jQuery.ajax with `async: false` return plain text although I have `dataType: 'json'`.

```
App.Language = {

    GetLanguageFile: function(lang) {
        var LangFile = GetJsonLanguageFile(lang);
        return LangFile;
    },

}

function GetJsonLanguageFile(lang) {
    var json = $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        // async: false,
        data: {action:'adminajax',method:'GetJsonLanguageFile',language: lang},
    })

    return json;
}
```

When function returned readyState: 1, in console I have object with key "responseText" and plain text result from json file but I can't get this key value, and when function is async, returned is object and I can get result but it's a plain text, although i have dataType: 'json'.

What I do wrong? How to make normal object from this json file content?

Comment: When `async` is at false, you don't get a jQXHR object as `$.ajax return`, is this what you mean?

Comment: No, when async is false function return object with right responseText. I don't wanna get this with async false

Comment: Ok, now with async false, $.ajax return json object. I had to change ' to " in json file but still doesn't work without async false

Answer (score 3):

Ajax call returns promise so you have to use `done` menthod to work with result, for example:

```
 function GetJsonLanguageFile(url, lang) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            // async: false,
            data: {action:'adminajax',method:'GetJsonLanguageFile',language: lang},
        });
}

GetJsonLanguageFile('some.url', lang).done(function(data) {
  // if it returns string insted of JSON try it:
  data = $.parseJSON(data);
  // do rest
  // window.json = data;
});
```

Comment: Because you can't return it, if you want to get it outside the function body you have to bind it to global variable, for example with `window.json = data;` but rather, you should do all the stuff inside function body.

Comment: This is actually a great candidate for an AJAX wrapper, even without the need to deprecated `asycn:false` Thank you, Love it